# GTK+/C Avoid preserving space for hidden widgets inside a GtkGrid

Tags: c, alignment, gtk3

A GtkGrid contains some widgets. When I hide some of this widgets there is still their space, instead I want to have all visible widgets re-aligned in a "natural way" (without preserving the space of the hidden widgets).

A little example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *label2, *label3;

static gboolean on_button_click (GtkButton *button, gpointer data) {
    gtk_widget_hide (label2);
    gtk_widget_hide (label3);
    return TRUE;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *label1 = gtk_label_new("Widget1");
    label2 = gtk_label_new("Widget2");
    label3 = gtk_label_new("Widget3");
    GtkWidget *label4 = gtk_label_new("Widget4");
    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hide widget2 and widget3");
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_button_click), NULL);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 10);

    GtkGrid *grid = (GtkGrid*)gtk_grid_new ();
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing((GtkGrid*)grid, 50);
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing((GtkGrid*)grid, 50);
    // 2 columns
    gtk_grid_insert_column (grid, 0);
    gtk_grid_insert_column (grid, 1);
    // 2 rows
    gtk_grid_insert_row (grid, 0);
    gtk_grid_insert_row (grid, 1);

    //Add widgets to the grid
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), label1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), label2, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), label3, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), label4, 2, 1, 1, 1);

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box), (GtkWidget*)grid, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

this program compiled with:

`` gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` test.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -o test ``

give this window:

[image]

clicking on the button, I get this result:

[image]

but I want this result:

[image]

What is the simplest way to do this?

p.s. I also need to show again the hidden widgets in the same position where they were when happen some events. Imagine to have another button that shows widget2 and widget3 again obtaining the same initial window.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove widget4 and re-pack it into widget2's space. (You attached the widgets to those particular cells in the grid, and so they'll stay there.)

It would be better still to use a different widget than `GtkGrid`, such as `GtkFlowBox`, to achieve what you want.

Comment: I want to avoid swapping childrens because isn't so efficient and simple with a big grid. I tried using `GtkFlowBox` but I've got the same result, so I think I have to write a function to swap them. The code I tried is here: http://pastebin.com/tsLPdh5h